# error: cannot connect to daemon

Tags: android, adb, processing

Almost a month ago I directly debugged application on my device with Processing (PDE) but today when I'm trying to deploy the application it doesn't work (keep in mind that I have updated SDK) it keeps getting an error as follows:

```
    error: cannot connect to daemon
nope: adb devices
    status: 1
    1065ms
    stdout:
* daemon not running. starting it now *
    stderr:
CreateProcess failure, error 2
* failed to start daemon *
```

Even if I run any of the command like *adb devices* or *adb shell* I get an error

```
 C:\Users\Hassan>adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now *
CreateProcess failure, error 2
* failed to start daemon *
error: cannot connect to daemon
```

I looked on several places and almost everyone said that kill the adb.exe process from task manager but any of that didn't work, I have also disabled the antivirus in case if that was messing, and also allowed the port 5037 in my firewall. what else can i try ?

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal and run following command

- `adb kill-server` and - `adb start-server`

Now run  `adb devices` to see the list of devices

I faced this problem while accessing the device in Appium Studio

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - where the error that I was getting was:

```
\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error executing "adb devices": ** daemon still not running
error: cannot connect to daemon

ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: \platforms\android\
cordova\run.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
```

It seems adb runs on port 5037 and when I checked somhow mozilla firefox was holding on to these ports

```
netstat -ao 5039
```

so killing mozilla firefox and running the command:

```
cordova run android
```

atleast I dont get this exception anymore

Answer (score -1):

running skipsoft's unified android toolkit fixed this for me
all i did was launch it, select model, select build and finally the device asked usb debugging permission. from there on adb worked